# Помогите решить задание на Python

Tags: python

1. Дан массив целых чисел. Найти сумму элементов с четными номерами и произведение элементов с нечетными номерами. Вывести сумму и произведение.
2. Переставить в одномерном массиве минимальный элемент и максимальный.

Сделал 1 , но не знаю как вывести из этого 2 задание

```py
from random import randint as g

s, p, l = 0, 1, [g(-10, 10) for i in range(g(10, 20))]

for i in l: (p := p * i) if i % 2 else (s := s + i)

print(f'{l}\nСумма чётных: {s}\nПроизведение нечётных: {p}')
```

Comment: `[min(l), max(l)]` или `[min(s, p), max(s, p)]`?

Comment: @entithat а «переставить»?

Comment: @andreymal, "представить" прочитал))

Comment: `l[l.index(min(l))], l[l.index(max(l))] = max(l), min(l)`

Comment: это вот прям тот код, который ты запускаешь и он у тебя работает?

Answer (score 0):

а в чем проблема?

если вам нужно просто решение - решайте в лоб

1. найдите минимальный и максимальный элементы в массиве через функции `min`, `max`
2. пройдите по массиву и найдите первые позиции таких элементов
3. поменяйте их местами

например так:

```
pos_min, pos_max, value_min, value_max = 0, 0, l[0], l[0]

for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i] < value_min:
        pos_min = i
        value_min = l[i]

    if l[i] > value_max:
        pos_max = i
        value_max = l[i]

l[pos_min], l[pos_max] = value_max, value_min
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from random import randint as g
from functools import reduce

l = [g(-10, 10) for i in range(g(10, 20))]
s = sum(l[::2])
p = reduce(type(l[0]).__mul__, l[1::2])
l[l.index(min(l))], l[l.index(max(l))] = max(l), min(l)

print(f'{l}\nСумма чётных: {s}\nПроизведение нечётных: {p}')
```